# Yii: How to add a simple checkbox in a view

Tags: php, html, checkbox, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to do add a checkbox to a view using the Yii2 framework.
Using HTML, JavaScript or Angular is very easy but I don't understand how to do it with Yii2.

I have a username input in the view called **_form.php**:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
</div>
```

And now I need a checkbox.

Is there any Yii documentation showing all its components?

This is my model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "user".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $auth_key
 * @property string $password_hash
 * @property string $password_reset_token
 * @property string $email
 * @property integer $status
 * @property integer $created_at
 * @property integer $updated_at
 */
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['username', 'auth_key', 'password_hash', 'email', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'required'],
            [['status', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'date','format' => 'd-M-yyyy H:m'],
            [['username', 'password_hash', 'password_reset_token', 'email'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['auth_key'], 'string', 'max' => 32],
            [['email'], 'unique'],
            [['password_reset_token'], 'unique'],
            [['username'], 'unique'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'Idadm',
            'username' => 'Nombre de usuario',
            'auth_key' => 'Auth Key',
            'password_hash' => 'Password Hash',
            'password_reset_token' => 'Password Reset Token',
            'email' => 'Email',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'created_at' => 'Creado',
            'updated_at' => 'Actualizado',
        ];
    }
}
```

So the attributes are: username, status, auth_key, email and password_reset_token. But I want to use a new attribute called population but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use    `->checkBox` instead of textInput

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->checkBox(['label' => 'your_label']) ?>
</div>
```

http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/yii2-0-activeform-input-fields/

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-html.html

Comment: I use <?= $form->field($model, 'population')->checkbox(); ?> but I get the error "Getting unknown property: app\models\User::population" Where should I define population?

Comment: seems that you have not an attribute population in your User model ... uodate you question and show me you User model please